# Effective way or guide to figure out Android default padding / margins to widgets

Tags: android

I've just wasted a ton of time going through a bunch of Android Design docs just to figure out some button default paddings / etc. It seems that this is due to the 9 patch images the default theme uses, and I'm just wondering is there a standard or something to assume that all default android widgets have in terms of padding and margin?

Like for example, if I set my EditText to have a height of 40dp, It's really 40 dp + 4dp of top / bottom padding I need to think about when laying out content.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try using below option in developer option in android , basically this display all layout bounds colored , It will not how how much padding is setted but it will show how widget in android created whether it hv padding and margin etc .

[image]

which will give u screen showing like this :

[image]